# How to install newest version of ffmpeg from ffmpeg.org

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

I want to install newest ffmpeg version in my server.
Current version:

> ffmpeg version 2.6.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>
> built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)

My Centos Version:

> Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
>
> CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
>
> Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
>
> Architecture: x86-64

And newest verion from http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

But I don't know how to install it from ffmpeg website.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method is to download an already compiled `ffmpeg` binary. Regularly updated static builds for Linux are available at:

https://www.johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Just download, extract, and execute. If desired move it somewhere in your `PATH` such as `/usr/local/bin` or `~/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using a software manager if you have one installed, otherwise follow this guide to compile it yourself.

Download the source tarball, in this case it's the green download button that says ffmpeg-3.3.3.tar.bz2. Open a terminal and move to the directory containing the tarball (by default, it's ~/Downloads). To move to the downloads directory type cd ~/Downloads and hit enter (you said you are a newbie so forgive me if I'm dumbing it down too much). Now unzip the tarball by typing tar -vxjf ffmpeg-3.3.3.tar.bz2 and hit enter. Next type cd ffmpeg-3.3.3 and hit enter. Type ./configure && make and hit enter. If successful, you need to run make install as root to complete the process. If you don't have the sudo command installed, you need to type su root, then type cd ../whateveryourusernameis/Downloads/ffmpeg-3.3.3 && make install. If you have sudo, you should use this instead. Type sudo make install while in the ffmpeg directory. If you run into problems during the build, be sure to post the errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snap to install more updated version of ffmpeg.
https://snapcraft.io/ffmpeg

```
sudo yum install snapd
sudo snap install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -version
```

Latest version of the ffmpeg in the Snap repository is 4.1 (January 2019)

Comment: error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/ffmpeg: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Comment: If you cannot communicate error, try running `systemctl status snapd.service` and see if it's running. If not, run `systemctl start snapd.service`